# MatLab webread not downloading full website page

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to fetch stock price data from Yahoo Finance (e.g. https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IGE/history?period1=1006729200&period2=1195081200&interval=1wk&filter=history&frequency=1wk). The problem is that the page loads dynamically by actively scrolling down.

The webread() function seems to not be able to execute Javascript in a webpage.

Is there an easy fix to this problem?

Thanks so much

I couldn't find useful options for the webread() function or other functions.

```
historicalPriceFile = webread("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IGE/history?period1=1006729200&period2=1195081200&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d");

% Extracting the date field to a cell array of cells.
% regexp(str,expr,'outkey') is used for matching regex. Outkey 'tokens' (portions of matched text corresponding 
% to portions of regex) is to have the text of each captured token stored in historicalPriceFile. 
% To create tokens, enclose part of the regular expression in parentheses.

dateField = regexp(historicalPriceFile,'<span data-reactid="\d+">(\w)+\s(\d)+[\,]\s(\d)+</span>',"tokens");
```

the outputs dateField and numField are 1x100 arrays while after scrolling to the bottom a total of 1504 lines apper.

Comment: The page has a "download data" button, can you not access that link instead?

Comment: You should have a look into the documentation about the specific REST-Interface of Yahoo. There should be a hint on how to get the specific data you desire... What is the actual output of your call of `webread`?

Comment: You shouldn't parse HTML with a regex. An alternative could be the text analytics toolbox.